# Optimise substring sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
   * from table 
where 
   substring(username,1) >= 'A' 
   and substring(username,1) <= 'C' 
   and height_in_meters * 100 > 140 
   and height_in_meters * 100 < 170;
```

what are the possible methods to speed up the query? It runs quite slowly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where username like '[A-C]%'`

would allow index use (should one be present) on `username` as opposed to passing `username` through a function which would always prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can optimize but

```
WHERE  username >= 'A' 
  AND  username < 'D' 
  AND  height_in_meters  > 1.4 
  AND  height_in_meters  < 1.7;
```

so you save the computation

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a lot of performance improvement from your query.
Maybe by removing the substring, but that's all I could figure.

```
select 
   * from table 
where 
   username >= 'A' AND username <= 'CZ' 
   and height_in_meters * 100 > 140 
   and height_in_meters * 100 < 170;
```

I added a `Z` after the `C` so the usernames starting with `C` are also included